# Arranging divs automatically while making one div bigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to create a gallery app where user mouseover on div and it gets bigger but rest remain the same height. You can see that happening in the example of this codepen snippet.

Problem: The problem is when I mouseover to some divs, it doesn't arranged properly. Can anyone help me with make it like so that no divs go out of the parent div and fill out the parent div.

```js
$( '.preview' ).on( 'mouseover', function() {
    $( '.preview' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'active' )
}).each( function( i, el ) {
    $( el ).append( '<span>' + i + '</span>' )
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 0;
}

.preview {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  transition: width 1s;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: left;
}

.active {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.preview>span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: black;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="preview active"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
  <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your `:hover` styling?

Comment: @TakitIsy $( '.preview' ).on( 'mouseover', function() {
    $( '.preview' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'active' )
}).each( function( i, el ) {
    $( el ).append( '<span>' + i + '</span>' )
});

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `Grid` Layout Module:

> [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

**Example:**

```js
$( '.preview' ).on( 'mouseover', function() {
    $( '.preview' ).removeClass( 'active' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'active' )
}).each( function( i, el ) {
    $( el ).append( '<span>' + i + '</span>' )
});
```

```css
.main {
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    /* CSS Grid */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 0
}
.preview {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    transition: all 1s
}
.active{
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
    <div class="preview active"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
    <div class="preview"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome example. Even I tried that with css-grid. That was my first attemept but I end up having the same problem with divs not filling properly. For example if you take hover the grid 16th you can see and if you suddenly move from 14-->15 or 9-->11 etc.

Comment: I feel stupid but… How to hover the 3, starting from the 0 ?

Comment: @TakitIsy No you are not stupid :/ sorry man don't feel like that. It is just you have across all the div. There is no other way :P